# How to print and update current time in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code that displays the user's local time:

HTML

```
<h1 id="time"></h1>
```

Script

```
var d = new Date();
var hours = d.getHours();
var minutes = d.getMinutes();

var mins=new Array(9);
mins[0]="00";
mins[1]="01";

...

mins[59]="59";

var MinName = mins[d.getMinutes()]; 
document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = hours+":"+MinName;
```

How can I modify this to update automatically as time passes, without reloading the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have a real simple solution:

```
setInterval(function() {
    var date = new Date();
    $('#time').html(
        date.getHours() + ":" + date.getMinutes() + ":" + date.getSeconds()
        );
}, 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `setInterval` http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

```
setInterval(function () {

   var d = new Date();
   var hours = d.getHours();
   var minutes = d.getMinutes();

   var mins=new Array(9);
   mins[0]="00";
   mins[1]="01";

   ...

   mins[59]="59";

   var MinName = mins[d.getMinutes()]; 
   document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = hours+":"+MinName;
}, 1000);
```